# Data received in controller from ajax is NULL?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am receiving null in both ProductData and ProductDetailsData when data is sent from ajax to controller. What could be the issue ?

IN CONTROLLER :

```
public bool UpdateProduct(Entity_Product ProductData, Entity_ProductDetails ProductDetailsData)
{
    return Json(DrugService.UpdateProduct(ProductData, ProductDetailsData));
}
```

IN JS FILE :

```
$(document).on("click", "#btn_update", function () {

    //Prepare data
    var ProductDataArray = [];
    var ProductDetailsDataArray = []; 

    ProductDataArray.push({
        "Name": $('#txt_drugname').val(),
        "CommercialName": $('#txt_drugcommercialname').val(),
        "PackageType": $("#dd_packagetype option:selected").val(),
        "DrugType": $("#dd_drugtype option:selected").val(),
        "DrugCode": $('#txt_drugcode').val(),
        "ProductId": $('#hdn_productid').val(),
        "Administration": $('#txt_administration').val(),
        "Manufacturer": $('#txt_manufacturer').val(),
        "Price": $('#txt_price').val(),
        "Strength": $('#txt_stregnth').val(),
        "StregnthUnit": $("#dd_stregnthunit option:selected").val(), 
        "Barcode": $('#txt_barcode').val(),
        "IsEnabled": $("#dd_isenabled option:selected").val(),  
        "UpdatedOn": new Date(),
        "UpdatedBy": 'UserNme',
    });


    ProductDetailsDataArray.push({
        "ProductId": $('#hdn_productid').val(),
        "ProductDetailsId": $('#hdn_productdetailid').val(),
        "Length": $('#txt_Legnth').val(),
        "Width": $('#txt_width').val(),
        "Height": $('#txt_height').val(),
        "ConversionRate": $('#txt_conversion').val(),
        "DrugForm": $("#dd_drugform option:selected").val(),
        "StoredAs": $("#dd_storedas option:selected").val()
    });



    //Send data
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Drug/UpdateProduct/',
        type: 'POST', 
        data: { 'ProductData': ProductDataArray, 'ProductDetailsData': ProductDetailsDataArray },
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: your `controller` should receive an object with those two properties `ProductData` & `ProductDetailsData` and not individual object. and add `FROMBODY` before the object in your `controller`

Comment: You're passing arrays with one item, while expecting single object. Don't do this: "var ProductDataArray = [];" Do this instead: "var ProductDataArray = { "ProductId": $('#hdn_productid').val(), ... };

Comment: @TiberSeptim It worked !! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have several issues in both AJAX and controller action method:

1) You're tried to pass arrays into `data` using `contentType` set to `application/json` without doing `JSON.stringify()` first, therefore it won't work since array required to pass either as JSON string or use `traditional: true` setting.

2) The action method parameter types are not set to array but a single entity class like viewmodel, you need to declare an object instead of array.

3) The controller action uses `bool` return type which should use `JsonResult` (or `ActionResult`) type.

Based from those mistakes mentioned above, try to use setup like below:

**jQuery**

```
$(document).on("click", "#btn_update", function () {
    var ProductDataArray = {
        "Name": $('#txt_drugname').val(),
        "CommercialName": $('#txt_drugcommercialname').val(),
        "PackageType": $("#dd_packagetype option:selected").val(),
        "DrugType": $("#dd_drugtype option:selected").val(),
        "DrugCode": $('#txt_drugcode').val(),
        "ProductId": $('#hdn_productid').val(),
        "Administration": $('#txt_administration').val(),
        "Manufacturer": $('#txt_manufacturer').val(),
        "Price": $('#txt_price').val(),
        "Strength": $('#txt_stregnth').val(),
        "StregnthUnit": $("#dd_stregnthunit option:selected").val(), 
        "Barcode": $('#txt_barcode').val(),
        "IsEnabled": $("#dd_isenabled option:selected").val(),  
        "UpdatedOn": new Date(),
        "UpdatedBy": 'UserNme',
    };

    var ProductDetailsDataArray = {
        "ProductId": $('#hdn_productid').val(),
        "ProductDetailsId": $('#hdn_productdetailid').val(),
        "Length": $('#txt_Legnth').val(),
        "Width": $('#txt_width').val(),
        "Height": $('#txt_height').val(),
        "ConversionRate": $('#txt_conversion').val(),
        "DrugForm": $("#dd_drugform option:selected").val(),
        "StoredAs": $("#dd_storedas option:selected").val()
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Drug/UpdateProduct/',
        type: 'POST', 
        data: JSON.stringify({ 'ProductData': ProductDataArray, 'ProductDetailsData': ProductDetailsDataArray }),
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            // do something
        }
    });
});
```

**Controller Action**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateProduct(Entity_Product ProductData, Entity_ProductDetails ProductDetailsData)
{
    return Json(DrugService.UpdateProduct(ProductData, ProductDetailsData));
}
```